# Popen() fails with "[WinError 6] The handle is invalid" in _cleanup() sometimes

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, popen

I'm working on a django project. One of the views calls Popen(). Most of the time everything works fine. But once in a while Popen() would fail with the following error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\***\views.py", line 116, in process_request
    proc = Popen(['python', exec_path, input_excel, current_tab, project])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 754, in __init__
    _cleanup()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 474, in _cleanup
    res = inst._internal_poll(_deadstate=sys.maxsize)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1146, in _internal_poll
    if _WaitForSingleObject(self._handle, 0) == _WAIT_OBJECT_0:
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

Restarting the server usually solves the problem but it could show up again later. Attempts immediately after the failure usually fail too (implemented with loops). Manually reloading the page multiple times solve the problem sometimes.

I also tried both 64 bit and 32 bit python versions. The problem shows on both.

It seems that _cleanup() manages the _active list which is used to avoid zombie processes. Considering I'm on windows, I commented out the _cleanup() in Popen() which seems to be working fine so far. Clearly it's not a proper fix. Any better idea?

Update:

Following eryksun's advice I looked closer at the handles. It seems that the process handle is closed by django's autoreload.py for some reason. See below for details.

```
---------------------------------------------------
try handle:

Handle(908)
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 49, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 88, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 97, in run
    autoreload.main(self.inner_run, None, options)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 325, in main
    reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 291, in python_reloader
    reloader_thread()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 267, in reloader_thread
    change = fn()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 204, in code_changed
    for filename in gen_filenames():
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 92, in gen_filenames
    _cached_filenames = clean_files(_cached_filenames)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 139, in clean_files
    if os.path.exists(filename):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\genericpath.py", line 19, in exists
    os.stat(path)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 452, in Close
    print(traceback.print_stack())
None
handle closed.
---------------------------------------------------
```

The above error information is generated by the modification below.

```
def Close(self, CloseHandle=_winapi.CloseHandle):
            print ('---------------------------------------------------')
            print ('try handle:')
            print (self)
            if not self.closed:
                self.closed = True
                CloseHandle(self)
                print(traceback.print_stack())
                print ('handle closed.')
            print ('---------------------------------------------------')
```

Later the exceptions complain about Handle (908).
I can't quite follow how os.stat(path) closed the handle and why the process isn't taken off the _active list by subprocess.py.

Comment: If the process is still running when `Popen.__del__` is called, it gets added to the `_active` list for `_cleanup` to poll it later. The process handle shouldn't be closed by any code in the subprocess module. I suspect that some other code is calling `CloseHandle`, which could be due to the handle value from a previously closed handle (e.g. a file handle) getting reused for the child process. Some code could be mistakenly closing the handle to your child process.

Comment: It makes sense. But I'm still confused on one thing. How come the handle becomes valid again afterwards. I noticed that typically after the process finishes, cleanup() run through just fine without complaining about invalid handle. Even if the same handle caused problems before.

Comment: A handle is an index into a per-process table that contains pointers to kernel objects. Once a handle is closed, the corresponding slot in the table and handle value are available for reuse, such as for the process handle used by `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: I updated in the question on what I think closed the handle. But I still can't figure out how to solve the problem.

Comment: That call stack is probably due to asynchronous garbage collection, given a reference cycle involving the `Popen` instance. But this does make it clear that the `Popen` instance is getting finalized, which finalizes / closes the referenced `Handle`. That can't happen if the `Popen` instance is referenced in the `_active` list. I'd have to do a lot more to instrument the sequence of events -- call tracing, logging, breakpoints (both Python pdb and Windows windbg). I think I'd rather switch to always calling the `wait` method to avoid the problem.

Comment: The `Popen` from a django view, so using `wait` would freeze the server. Overall `subprocess` is probably just a bad module to use for the application. I switched to `celery` which worked much better. Thanks for all the help again.